# How to create HTML gallery elements with blueimp gallery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blueimp

I'm using [blueimp Gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery) in a Rails app. Its a great plugin!

I've successfully added additional gallery elements by following the [instructions](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#additional-gallery-elements), but now I'm trying to add an HTML element (a link).

The html is currently rendered as text. How can I create HTML gallery elements in blueimp gallery?

Comment: Hey.. were you able to solve this? I am also trying to put custom HTML content on click of an individual item in the gallery. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the HTML in the Title using a code snippet from BlueImp. It overrides the setTitle to use html.

http://jsfiddle.net/j8U9K/5/

```
blueimp.Gallery.prototype.setTitle = function (index) {
var obj = $(this.list[index]);
this.titleElement.html(obj.data('title-html'));
};
```

The above fiddle shows this working

Answer (score 0):

You can use blueimp gallery events (see [Documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#jquery-events))

Here how I added a "Download link":

In HTML:

```
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-filter=":even">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <p class="download"></p> <!-- This is my custom tag -->
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
```

In CSS:

```
.blueimp-gallery > .close, .blueimp-gallery > .download {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    left: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000000;
    top: 50px;
}
```

In JS:

```
$('#blueimp-gallery').on('slide', function(event, index, slide) {
    var href = $('.slide[data-index=' + index + '] .slide-content').attr('src');
    var $a = $('<a />', { href:href, text:'Download'});
    $('.download').html($a);
});
```